# Refernce data classes from different local data models

Tags: wakanda

In Wakanda it is possible to create several local data models. How can I reference a related entity of data class B from data model B in a data class of data model A? I tried to do the same thing as if both data classes were in the same model, but with different data models the data classes from different data models obviously don't know each other. Or is this not planned and both data models exist independently of each other?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let dsForModelB = solution.getApplicationByName("B").ds;
```

Edit: Just re-read your question and it looks like you want to create relations between data classes from different models. I don't think that is possible.

If you think about it, if two data classes are related, they should probably be in the same model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
That's what I thought. The documentary says,"Local data model: can be used to split your (existing) WakandaDB model into different parts." That sounds to me as if you could split one and the same model, but if I choose "Model" -> "New Model" -> "Local", then a new model is created and nothing is split. So the docu says something else than the function does.
I thought it would be possible to split an existing model into different parts, but in the background it is still an entire model, so that the handling becomes easier in the Model editor for example.